# How to import Python variables found from a website found using regular expression findall (E.g. product name, picture, price) into a HTML document?

Tags: python, html, regex, findall

Hi guys i'm trying to figure out how to import variables that I have saved into lists into a HTML document.

```
##DOG ITEMS
dog_url = 'https://feed.zazzle.com/rss?qs=dogs'
dog_contents = urlopen(dog_url).read()
###DOG ITEM INFO
dog_names = findall('<title>[<![]+CDATA[[]([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)'
```

I want to be able to post the list data into the HTML document based on its index. So dog_names[0] = "item 1" posted as text.

This is my HTML code.

```
file_name = open('invoice.html','w')
message = """<html>

<head>
<center>
<h1 style="font-size:45px;">BAD BUSINESS PLAN PTY LTD. INVOICE</h1>
<img src="companyLogo.jpg" width="400" height ="400" alt="Company Logo">
</center>
</head>

<body>
<p><table border="2"; align="center"><td>%dog_names</td></table></p>
</body>

</html>"""

file_name.write(message)
file_name.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do? Do you want to extract a table from an existing html-page into a python-list, or do you want to output the variables you find in your html_template?

Comment: So I've already extracted the information from the website and then want to post the information that is saved into the python list, for example dog_names. So if I posted dog_names[0] it would say it in a string in the html document I created.

Answer (score 0):

checkout pythons [format syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). You can use it for your string output as follows:

```
message = """<html>

<head>
<center>
<h1 style="font-size:45px;">BAD BUSINESS PLAN PTY LTD. INVOICE</h1>
<img src="companyLogo.jpg" width="400" height ="400" alt="Company Logo">
</center>
</head>

<body>
<p><table border="2"; align="center"> {dog_names} </table></p>
</body>

</html>"""

line_template = "<tr><td> {dog_name} </td></tr>"

dog_name_list = [ line_template.format(dog_name = dog_name) for dog_name in dog_names ]
dog_names = "".join(dog_name_list)

print message.format(dog_names=dog_names)
```